# Angular 2, C# MVC ApiController: Error on Get Request from C# Rest Api

Tags: c#, rest, angular, typescript

i have problem with c# ApiController, i have some like this:

```
public class Heroes
{
    public int userId;
    public int id;
    public string title;
    public string body;
}

public class HeroesController : ApiController
{
    // ...

    // GET: api/Heroes/5
    public Heroes Get(int id)
    {
        Heroes u = new Heroes() 
        { 
            userId = 1, title = "some titile", body = "some body" 
        };
        return u;
    }

    // ...
}

public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes
            .Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
    }
}
```

the result of Chrome extension *Restlet Client* is correctly (200 ok) 
Request 'Get' is send on http://localhost:63854/api/Heroes/5

```
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 0,
"title": "some titile",
"body": "some body"
}
```

but, when i send Get Request in angular i recive a error message

> TypeError:
>   **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_rxjs_Observable**.Observable.throw is not a function

and (in angular) if i use outside rest api, some like this 
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts 
its works correcty, retun result, and i don't have any error messages.

Where is mistakes in Rest Api in c# controller ? 
I don't suspects that errors is on the angular side.

sorry for my bad English :c

Comment: the error is on the angular side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this import statement to the top of your client:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

Comment: thanks, but now i recive error: 0 -  {"isTrusted":true}

Comment: only on post, for fix get i add <system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>